# How can I display date in the input field of NgbDatePicker, in the initial load

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using NgbDatePicker, and on the Initial Load of my page, I want today's date to be displayed in the input field of my datepicker. 
Currently on the initial load, the placeholder value is being displayed. Is there any way to display today's date in the input field on load.

```
<input width="100px" class="form-control " [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" #date
        (ngModelChange)="dateSelected(date.value)" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" name="dp" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker"
        pattern="[0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2}" [minDate]="{year: 2010, month: 1, day: 1}" [maxDate]="maxDate"
        [markDisabled]="isDisabled" />
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary fas fa-calendar-alt" (click)="d.toggle()"
          (change)="dateSelected($event.target.value)" type="button"
          (ngModelChange)="dateSelected($event.target.value)"></button>
      </div>
```

Expected Result: On load, today's date should be displayed in the input field.

Actual Result: Only placeholder's value is being display.

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: I just updated my question, with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to fully utilise your NgBoostrap DatePicker module, you can import the [NgbCalendar service](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbCalendar) into your component.ts, and use it to get today's date. Do note that NgBootstrap date pickers do not accept the usual JavaScript Date object or date strings as an input, as it uses the [NgbDateStruct](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbDateStruct) interface.

First, import NgbCalendar into your component.ts,

```
import { NgbCalendar, NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

Then, use the `getToday()` method and assign today's date to the `selectedDate` property. Your datepicker should be initialised with today's date.

```
selectedDate: NgbDateStruct = undefined;

constructor(private calendar: NgbCalendar) { 
  this.selectedDate = calendar.getToday()
}
```

Alternatively, you may set today's date using Vanilla JavaScript,

```
constructor(private calendar: NgbCalendar) { 
  const today = new Date();
  this.selectedDate = {
    day: today.getDate(),
    month: today.getMonth() + 1,
    year: today.getFullYear()
  };
}
```

Comment: @Satyaram Glad to help!

Comment: Cannot upvote as I don't have sufficient reputation to do so, but i marked as accepted. Thanks WestJun

Answer (score 0):

Please note that ngbDatepicker model is an NgbDate object. You must set [ngModel]="selectedDate" variable inside your constructor or onInit method, something like this.

```
ngOnInit() {
var today = new Date();
this.selectedDate = new NgbDate(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate())
}
```

Thanks